# How to save screenshots including test results, etc. when the test is finished in pytest

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I want to save a screenshot when a test fails.
However, the screenshot name must include the information used in the test.

example

-> Currently my code is able to send the `city` I used in the test.
However, it does not operate according to success or failure.
How can I make the test receive a variable as well and act on success/failure?

(The file name I want: {city}*{id}*{pass/fail}.png
paris_testaccount01_pass.png)

test_example.py

```
class TesExample(BaseTest):
    def test_example(self, capture_screenshot):
        city = "paris"
        id = "testaccount01"
        # ~~ Skip test content ~~

        capture_screenshot(self.driver, city)
```

BaseTest.py

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("get_browser")
class BaseTest:
    pass
```

conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture()
def capture_screenshot():
    def _capture_screenshot(get_browser, name):
        driver = get_browser
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file(f'../Screenshots/{name}.png')
        return _capture_screenshot
    return _capture_screenshot
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the question : you want to make a screenshot but you are not able to do so because the tes fails before ?

Comment: @jossefaz I can take a screenshot when the test fails. (By using request.node.rep_call.failed .)
However, you cannot include the information used in the test (such as city and id) in the screenshot file name. ( Information that is not covered in conftest but handled in testcase)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `pytest-html` for reporting and If you would take screenshot in case of fail, you can use following code in your ***conftest***:

```
@mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
    if report.when == 'call':
        xfail_state = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail_state) or (report.failed and not xfail_state):
            mydriver = item.funcargs['driver']
            screenshot = mydriver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image(screenshot, ''))
    report.extra = extra
```